# sqlserver - How to append column data from function and pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First I join two tables

```
select a.name, a.owner from asset a
join person p on a.owner = p.name and p.age > 50
```

which returns result like

```
name  | owner
PC    | Mike
Phone | Peter
Mouse | Mike
Snack | Peter
```

I have a function

```
select * from asset_info('PC')
```

which returns result like

```
key         | value
price       | 1000
color       | white
expire_date | 2017-01-10
```

So I change the query

```
select top 1 * from
(
    select key, value from asset_info('PC')
) d
pivot
(
    max(value)
    for key in (price, color)
) piv
```

which returns result like

```
price | color
1000  | white
```

Here is my expected result

```
name  | owner | price | color
PC    | Mike  | 1000  | white
Phone | Peter | 500   | white
Mouse | Mike  | 20    | black
Snack | Peter | 100   | yellow
```

How can I get this through an instant query without temp table?

Comment: It looks like your function only returns the values for - in this instance - the `PC` records?  Do you have the SQL behind the function so you can build your own logic?

Comment: @iamdave yes, if the parameter is ```Phone```, it will return corresponding values.

Comment: You cannot get your desired result without either using a version of the function that doesn't filter by asset name (probably by getting the code behind it) or by using a `while` loop to insert into a temp table.

Comment: so sad...... :(

Comment: Are you unable to get the SQL that is behind the function?

Comment: @iamdave yeah, i cannot modify it or add new functions either

Comment: You don't need to modify or add new functions.  If you can just get the code behind the function (either through SSMS or by speaking to your database owner), you can include the relevant logic as just part of your query without the filter on `asset name`